# how can I use list * i in single line for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, lambda

Current code:

```
res = []
for i in range(0,len(nums),2):
    res.extend([nums[i+1]]*nums[i])       
return res
```

Expected:

```
res = [([nums[i+1]]*nums[i]) for i in range(0,len(nums),2)]
```

Difference:

gives : `[[1,1],[2,2,2]]`

expected: `[[1,1,2,2,2]]`

Comment: A list comprehension is equivalent to `res.append(...)` not `res.extend(...)`.

Comment: What is `nums`?

Comment: Can't be done, unless you use `list(itertools.chain(*[...]))` or something

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use multiple clauses in the list comprehension to achieve this (supposing you want `nums[i]` copies of `nums[i + 1]` in the list, and you want the list to be one-dimensional):

```
nums = [2, 1, 3, 2]
res = [nums[i+1] for i in range(0,len(nums),2) for _ in range(nums[i])]
# [1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

Here, I use both `for i in range(0, len(nums), 2)`, as was in your original code, and `for _ in range(nums[i])` to simulate the repetition provided by `* nums[i]`.

You can then enclose this in another list if you want.